# getJSON and retrieving data from an Array

Tags: php, jquery, json

I made a PHP script:

```
function getData(){

  $DBH = connectDB(********);

  $STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM table');

  $tData = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($tData);

}
```

This is executed in getData.php. The fields are ID, name, lastname, age. Basically, get's all the table's values and put them in a JSON array.

I dont know how to complete the JQuery's getJSON function to retrieve, for example, the ID 5 register or the name = "John" one.

The examples at JQuery.com are a bit complex due my little understanding of how all this stuff works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('getData.php',function(data) {
        $.each(data,function(i, item) {
            alert(item.ID + '->' + item.name + '->' + item.lastname );
        });
    });
});
```

**NB:** the way on how you get the single ID, NAME depend on how the `json_encode($tData)` is formatted, so, you do better if you post to us the echoed json!

Comment: [{"ID":"1","name":"John","lastname":"Doe","age":"22"}...]

Comment: i have updated the code, sorry my bad, now it should work as expected! ;)

Comment: What's the i for in $.each(data,function(i, item) { ??

Comment: @Gabriel A. Zorrilla - `i` is the incrementer like `i++` in a classic for loop

Answer (score 1):

$.getJSON("you page.php",
  {
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      Alert(item["yourfildname"]);
    });
  });

Comment: Thanks Marco. But where are you supposed to call the PHP script to retreive the data?

Comment: It does not use $.getJSON and i get "undefined" in the alert prompt.